# socket.io - multiple events performance

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

About using socket.io events.

Whats the better approach:

```
socket.on('message', function (message) {
   if(message.message1) {
       // do something
   } else if (message.message2) {
       // do something else
   } else if ...
});
```

VS

```
socket.on('message1', function (message) {
   // do something
});
socket.on('message2', function (message) {
   // do something else
});
...
```

Is there a limit of number of events where performance decreases?

Second option seems to be the maintenance and readability option, but an event for every type of message seems like to much.

Is there any other programming paradigms or best practise for this?

Comment: There's exactly zero reason to use the first approach. Just use the standard socket.io routing.

Comment: What about a big number of events? No performance decrease?

Comment: The first approach would see a performance decrease, not the second one.

Comment: How many types of messages do you have? If only let's say ten then it doesn't matter at all. You won't notice any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The routing of messages on events in socket.io relies on an object as map.

The implementation can be seen here : https://github.com/component/emitter/blob/master/index.js#L45

Objects as maps are very fast. In the worst case (i.e. when the optimizing compiler couldn't replace them with classes) they work as [hash tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).

This routing is much much faster than the `if` of your first solution. Whatever the number of event types you have, don't use this solution but the standard one.